# how to get ajax "success" and "error" response using php-crud-api

Tags: php, json, ajax, api

I am having issues validating a response from API.
I am using [php-crud-api](https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api/) and I am passing the values from my login form to the url **filter[]**, the server responds with a **200 OK** and returns the json data from the table. However I don't need the json data just a "**success**" or "**error**" response. Any help would be amazing. Thank you in advance for any feedback.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#login-button").click(function() {
        log_email = $("#login_email").val();
        log_password = $("#login_password").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://www.website.com/api.php/users?",
            crossDomain: true,
            data: "filter[]=email,eq,email=" + log_email + "&filter[]=password,eq,password=" + log_password,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                if (data == "null") {
                    console.log("Email and Password DIDN'T match");
                    $( "#invalid-login" ).popup( "open" );
                } 
                else if (data == "true") {
                    console.log("it's a !!MATCH!!");
                    window.location = "content.html";
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: If all you need is a success or error response you would echo those responses in your PHP with no other output.

Comment: have you looked at the api documentation and file? It's documented ok but it's not amazing. I looked at the php and was instantly lost. Maybe I'm just too new at this :(

Answer (score 0):

I've read the documentation of https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api and its written that it will return the output in json format only "Condensed JSON ouput: first row contains field names", so you need to change your code accordingly or you can use some other option.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily the API developer got back to me and he offered the following solution:

in the ajax call add the following line to limit the output:

```
+"&columns=email"
```

Replase:

```
if (data == "null") {
```

With:

```
if (data.users.records.length==0) {
```

In the else clause, just replace:

```
else if (data == "true") {
```

with:

```
else {
```

RESULT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#login-button").click(function() {
        log_email = $("#login_email").val();
        log_password = $("#login_password").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://www.website.com/api.php/users?",
            data: "filter[]=email,eq,"+log_email+"&filter[]=password,eq,"+log_password+"&columns=email",
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.itouchyou.records.length == 0) { 
                    //FAIL
                    $( "#invalid-login" ).popup( "open" );
                    console.log("Email and Password DIDN'T match");
                } 
                else { 
                    // SUCCESS
                    window.location = "content.html";
                    console.log("it's a !!MATCH!!");
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```